# Compile LESS, minify CSS and JS and output to build directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

So, I recently started with ASP MVC4 and on my journey I discovered several new technologies and frameworks, such as LESS, Bootrap etc. (because I haven't done any web application in years!) whose capabilities completely blew my mind. I worked my way through various tutorials and the only thing I learnt is: How bad they work together. I just can't get anything working and its extremely frustrating.

What I want to achieve:

1. Having bootraps less source along with other site specific less files in one directory, such as `Content\style\less\*.less` (also for JS files: `Scripts\*.js`)
2. Compile LESS files at build (pre-build)
3. Copy all files to custom build directory, e.g. `bin\style\*.css`
4. Minimize and optimize css and js files in output directory.
5. Bundle all together at runtime

What I fail at:

1. Copy ALL files to custom build directory. Visual Studio just compiles the code and copies it to `bin\`
2. Compile less files properly. I created a pre-build instruction with the dotless.compiler.exe, but it fails at simple tasks, such as copying to new directory or reverse directory compiling (when I say compile `\Content\style\less\*.less` it just compiles every file in this directory, not in directories below.
3. Optimization and minify: It seems that the Web.Optimization bundling instruction only work at runtime, not at build time!

I hope anyone can help me.

Technologies and frameworks I used: ASPX, MVC4, Razor, dotless, Bootstrap, Web.Optimization

**Edit**: *Regards the output task: Am I expecting too much? Compiling an application and copy every necessary resource to a seperate `\bin` (build) directory is a common element in .NET application production lifecycle for ever. Why not for ASP sites, since they are called `applications` aswell.*

Comment: First, install Web Essentials 2012 (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)

Comment: @haim770 May this help with my problems? I'm not very familiar with the Web Essentials package, I just thought it added better support for HTML5, IntelliSense etc. stuff.

Comment: It will compile your `LESS` files to regular `CSS`. the rest you can achieve using Post-Build events.

Comment: @haim770 Installed it and tried it. It indeed created a new folder `\Content\css` (not the directory I wanted, but I can life with that!) but it is empty. No LESS file got compiled anywhere? Do I have to configure something somewhere?

Comment: Check Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Web Essentials. make sure LESS compilation is checked.

Comment: @haim770 Found it! Well, now it creates an additional `css` folder inside my `less` folder, but still empty. Now I have two `css` folders in my project that get auto created on every build but both remain empty. This is getting more and more ridiculous. :/

Comment: Try to build. also, try to open your main `.less` file and save it.

Comment: @haim770 Opening the main .less files did the trick. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Something to keep in mind with regard to publishing your Web Application is that the process is much different from other project types such as Class Libraries and Console Apps. Visual Studio has a built in publish feature that will allow you to package your application for use in production. You can find a brief tutorial on the subject here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWLCZukjPz0 

I only bring this up on account of your comments regarding compiling the application.

Answer (score 0):

After installing [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6), Shift+Alt+Y is the default keybinding for triggering a recompile of all .less-files.